# How to rotate an object in three js around its axis?

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation

I want to spin a globe object around its y axis. I found a function for that:

```
function rotateAroundObjectAxis(object, axis, radians) {

  var rotationMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();

  rotationMatrix.makeRotationAxis(axis.normalize(), radians);
  object.matrix.multiply(rotationMatrix);
  console.log("object matrix: " + object.matrix.elements);
  object.rotation.setFromRotationMatrix( object.matrix );
}
```

However, the rotation stops at a specific point. I assume this is because the value of object.matrix which is used for the matrix multiplication with my calculated rotation matrix gets <= 0. How would I approach a continuous rotation?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use object.rotateY(rad) https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.rotateY. For continous rotation use small angle and update in render loop.

Comment: That's weird. I get the same result. The object just stops at a specific point